# Old Unity project : scale with resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, responsive-design, resolution, scaling, unityscript

I have this old Unity project : 3 years old. And it was developed for a specific resolution : iPad 1024*768.

I want to rebuild this on Windows but I want to make it resolution responsive. 
Do someone knows a way to automatically rescale GUI that have been made before the Canvas & Canvas Scaler ?
It Would be MUCH appreciated, 
Thank you for reading, 
Bye

Comment: Did you use obsolate Unity3D GUI System, or other solutions like NGUI? Answer depends on it.

Comment: BTW it is ALWAYS bad idea to develop UI that works fine only for one resoultion/aspect ratio. Now you pay for this mistake ;). Even old Unity3D GUI gives you control to not do that.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, I didn't make this projects, I agree with you on this point. 
I have 2 projects and one is with old gui system and the other use this plugin called UGH By Graveck, I think it's kinda like NGUI.

Answer (score 1):

A very hackish way to do this is multiply all of your height and width values by the ratio of the original width/height to your desired width/height. However, you will battle placement issues and stretching.

My team ended up re-building the GUI for our application because of this. It saved us time in the long-haul and that's what I would suggest.

Comment: Ye thanks for your answer, I used to use this trick but I always had the issues you were talking about. 
I think i'm going to fully rebuild it as you suggest. It will be clean and reusable. 
I wait a little longer if anyone come up with a brillant workaround.